# Не работает СSS правило

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
ul.todo li .buttons {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}


ul.todo li .buttons button {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background: none;
border: 0;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}

<ul class="todo">
        <li>This is an item!</li>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </ul>

     <ul class="todo">
        <li>This is an item!</li>
    </ul>

     <ul class="todo">
        <li>This is an item!</li>
    </ul>
```

Не хотят работать первые два правила.

Comment: Что именно у вас не работает? У вас незавершенный css код и какой-то кусок html кода. Что вы ожидаете увидеть? И ни одного css правила.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `ul.todo li .buttons` некорректен, в `LI` нет класса `.button`, данный `DIV` идёт после  `LI` и не находится в нём.Вставьте `DIV` с классом `.buttons` в `LI`.

```
<ul class="todo">
        <li>This is an item!
        <div class="buttons">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Какая глупая ошибка!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, бывает )